# How to Skip strrpos Entry

Tags: php, string

Is it possible to skip a strpos/strrpos position?

```
    $string = "This is a cookie 'cookie'.";
    $finder = "cookie";
    $replacement = "monster";
    if (strrpos($string, $finder) !== false)
        str_replace($finder, $replacement, $string);
```

I want to skip the 'cookie' and replace the plain cookie so it'll result in "This is a monster 'cookie'."

I don't have qualms with it finding 'cookie' first and then checking it (Obviously necessary to determine it shouldn't be replaced), but I want to make sure that while 'cookie' is still there, I can use the same function to find the unquoted cookie.

Alternatively, is there a function I haven't found yet (Through hours of searching) to get all indices of a particular word so I can check them all through a loop without the use of regex?

It's important that it's the index, not the word itself, as there are other checks that have to be done based on where in the string the word's located.

Comment: If any of the provided solutions worked please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives the required replacement as well as the position of the replaced word.

```
$string = "This is a cookie 'cookie'."; 
$finder = "cookie";
$replacement = "monster";
$p = -1; // helps get position of current word
$position = -1; // the position of the word replaced
$arr = explode(' ',$string);
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 1){
// Find the position $p of each word and
// Catch $position when a replacement is made
if($i == 0){$p = 0;} else {  $w =$arr[$i - 1]; $p  += strlen($w) + 1;}
if($arr[$i] == $finder){ if($position < 0){$position = $p;}$arr[$i] = $replacement;}}
$newstring = implode(' ', $arr);
echo $newstring; // gives: This is a monster 'cookie'
echo '<br/>';
echo $position;  // gives 10, the position of replaced element.
```

For the position, the assumption is that the sentence has only single spaces because spaces are used in the `explode` and `implode` functions. Otherwise a case of double or larger spaces would require modifications, possibly by replacing spaces with a unique character or set of characters such as `@$#` which would be used as the first argument of the `explode` and `implode` functions.

The code could be modified to capture more than one replacement, e.g. by capturing each replaced position in an array instead of testing for `if(position < 0)`. This would also require to change the way `$position` is computed because its values are affected by the lengths of previous replacements.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a regex instead:

Try the following:

```
$string = "This is a cookie 'cookie'.";

var_dump(preg_replace("/(?<!')(cookie)/", ' monster', $string));
```

This uses `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace` to replace the string.

**Edit:** You can use `preg_match` to get the position of the matched regex in the string like:

```
$string = "This is a cookie 'cookie'.";
$finder = "cookie";
preg_match("/(?<!')(" . preg_quote($finder) . ")/", $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
var_dump($matches);
```

And you can use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to make sure that [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) doesn't treat the `$finder` var as a `regex`. And the difference in performance is very subtle between `preg` and other string functions in php. You can run some benchmarks to see how it varies in your case.

Comment: I'd prefer avoiding regex, given regex tends to like to treat strings as possibly executable code. Regex's also generally a bit slower and doesn't provide indices (That I know of) to figure out where in the string the word's located prior to replacement.

Comment: @Drake can you clarify what you mean by "regex tends to like to treat strings as possibly executable code"? And what do you mean by indices? Are you looking for the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag?

Comment: @Gordon If you run a snippet of code through Regex (Where (cookie) is, input something with } or anything else code-wise in the form of a variable), it'll act as though that's part of the running script and result in an error at best, or user-written server-side code at worst. Regex likes to pretend variable strings are code, whereas other find/replace functions don't. As far as indices, I mean like strpos/strrpos. It gives the index of the first character of the found word. I think I've created a solution that will work but have to implement it to be sure.

Comment: @Drake you mean when interpolating user provided strings into the regex pattern? There is `preg_quote` for that.

Comment: @Gordon Will have to look into that one. Thanks. :)

Comment: @mega6382 I'll take a look at the edit when I'm able. The concern is that the string could be incredibly long, so the faster the better, but I'll try it out as long as I don't run into any issues with it. I only know what I've bumped into and read.

Answer (score 1):

We can do also like this for short-hand :

Include also previous letter to function str_replace like this :

```
$string = "This is a cookie 'cookie'.";
echo str_replace('a cookie','a monster',$string);
```

Comment: That assumes I'm going to have control over what the user types and/or every single string, though. The string is an example, not necessarily the final to-be-replaced string. This also doesn't check for location in the string for any other calculations necessary based on close-to-beginning or close-to-end.